# Associate 2 array values

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an issue understanding how I can check for the same values from 2 arrays and display the label that's inside 1 array if it matchs the other array value.
I tried with .indexOf() but didn't got it to work, if anyone have some exemples/advices I'll be glad to ear them, thank you!

Here's what they look like :

**First Array**, values can be from 1 to 10 ATM.

[image]

**Second Array**

[image]

So I need to make the values from **first array** match with the labels from the **second array** and render them in my HTML with an *ngFor.

**component.ts**

```
export class TopComponent implements OnInit {

  labels: any[];
  filterForm: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;
  test: any[];
  filteredLabels: any[];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private service: QuotationMenuService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getStructure().subscribe(res => {
      this.labels = res.parts;
      this.test = res.labels_levels

      console.log(this.test);
      this.applyFilters();
      this.filterLevels();
      })
  }

@Output() sendDynamicParts = new EventEmitter<number>();


  get f() {
    return this.filterForm.controls;
  }


  firstLevel: any;
  dynamicParts1: any;
  dynamicParts2: any;
  dynamicParts3: any;
  dynamicLevels1: any;
  dynamicLevels2: any;
  dynamicLevels3: any;
  isShow: boolean;
  valLevel1: number;
  valLevel2: number;
  valLevel3: number;


  filterLevels(){
    // Get and display first level
      let level1 = this.labels.map(function (obj) {
        return obj.l1;
      });
      level1 = level1.filter(function(v,i) { return level1.indexOf(v) == i; });
      this.firstLevel = level1;
      console.log(this.firstLevel.valueOf());

  }

  // Render second level depending on first level
  dynamicFilter1(id){
    this.valLevel1 = id;
    this.dynamicParts1 = this.labels.filter(x => x.l1 === id);
    console.log(this.dynamicParts1)
    let dynLevel1 = this.labels.map(function (obj) {
      if (obj.l1 === id){
        return obj.l2;
      }
    });
    dynLevel1 = dynLevel1.filter(function(v,i) { return dynLevel1.indexOf(v) == i; });
    // Remove undefined
    this.dynamicLevels1 = dynLevel1.filter(function (el) {
      return el != undefined;
    });
    console.log(dynLevel1);
  }

  // Render third level depending on first AND second level
  dynamicFilter2(id1){
    this.valLevel2 = id1;
    this.dynamicParts2 = this.labels
      .filter(x =>x.l1 === this.valLevel1 && x.l2 === id1)
    console.log(this.dynamicParts2);
    this.dynamicLevels2 = this.labels
      .filter(x =>x.l1 === this.valLevel1 && x.l2 === id1)
      .map(function (obj) {
      return obj.l3;
    }
      );
    let dynLevel2 = this.dynamicLevels2;
    this.dynamicLevels2 = this.dynamicLevels2.filter(function (v,i) {
      return dynLevel2.indexOf(v) == i;
    });
    this.dynamicLevels2 = this.dynamicLevels2.filter(function (el) {
      return el != null;
    });
    this.sendDynamicParts.emit(id1);
    console.log(this.dynamicLevels2);
  }

  dynamicFilter3(id){
    this.valLevel3 = id;
    // Get full parts corresponding
    this.dynamicParts3 = this.labels
      .filter(x =>x.l1 === this.valLevel1 && x.l2 === this.valLevel2 && x.l3 === id);
    console.log(this.dynamicParts3);
    this.dynamicLevels3 = this.labels
      .filter(x =>x.l1 === this.valLevel1 && x.l2 === id)
      .map(function (obj) {
          return obj.l3;
        }
      );
    let dynLevel2 = this.dynamicLevels3;
    this.dynamicLevels3 = this.dynamicLevels3.filter(function (v,i) {
      return dynLevel2.indexOf(v) == i;
    });
    this.dynamicLevels3 = this.dynamicLevels3.filter(function (el) {
      return el != null;
    });
    console.log(this.dynamicLevels3);
  }


  applyFilters() {
    this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        level1: [''],
        level2: [''],
        level3: [''],
      }
    )
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div>
  <form *ngIf="filterForm" [formGroup]="filterForm" >
      <nav class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row reduceHeight40 navbar-light mainNav">
        <input type="button" formControlName="level1" [value]="first" class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link alu hovAlu"
           style="background-color: #0076AC;" *ngFor="let first of firstLevel" (click)="dynamicFilter1(first)" placeholder="{{first}}">
      </nav>
        <div class="container alu  dpf  navbar-light">
         <nav class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row navbar-light" >
           <input  style="background-color: #0076AC;" formControlName="level2" [value]="second" type="button"  (click)="dynamicFilter2(second)"
                class="flex-sm-fill reduceHeight25 borderless wdt10 text-sm-center nav-link" *ngFor="let second of dynamicLevels1" placeholder="{{second}}">
         </nav>
        </div>
          <div class="container alu  dpf navbar-light">
            <nav class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row navbar-light" >
              <input  style="background-color: #0076AC;" type="button" [value]="third" formControlName="level3"
                  class="flex-sm-fill reduceHeight25 borderless wdt10 text-sm-center nav-link" (click)="dynamicFilter3(third)"
                      *ngFor="let third of dynamicLevels2"  placeholder="{{third}}">
            </nav>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT** : Raw data example :

```
0:
part: "Alu_network_40"
l1: 1
l2: 2
l3: null
diam: Array(1)
    0: 6
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
price1: "263.69"
price2: "2216.55"
cur: null
desc: null
__proto__: Object
```

**First Array** :

```
{ 1: "Aluminium"
2: "Network"
3: "Drops"
4: "Drops Aluminium"
5: "Drops 316L"
6: "Take Off"
7: "Misc"
8: "VANNE"
9: "POINT OF USE"
10: "DESCENTE DE PURGE"
__proto__: Object }
```

F.Y.I data that needs to match are `l1, l2, l3` and the numbers inside the first array

Comment: Please include data as text, not as pictures of text. If the data do not have circular references, you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` to get a nicely printed representation.

Comment: The first does not seem to be an array, but an object with properties/fields `1, 2, 3, etc.`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey , sorry I edited it

Comment: @Silvermind and is there any way to compare values between the 2 ? Or should I make it an array ?

Comment: Am I correct when I think you mean that you want a third array that says `['Network', 'Drops', 'Take Off', 'Misc']`?

Comment: @Silvermind Actually, I just want to match **l1,l2,l3** to their appropriated label situated in the first array, example : if the value of my input is  **1** ( 1 coming from l1), it should render **"Aluminium"** which is inside the other array